# Compress all pictures of a PowerPoint presentation at once using VBA

Tags: python, vba, powerpoint

I have PowerPoint presentations I generate automatically containing heavy pictures. PowerPoint has a "Compress Pictures" function to reduce the resolution.

I am looking for VBA code that compresses, at the same resolution, all the pictures in the presentation of the macro.

In other words, "Compress Pictures" with box "Apply only to this picture" unchecked.

The below code steps through all pictures, but I want to compress without popping the box choice.

[How can I (programmatically) step through all pictures and let the user choose compression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74551170/how-can-i-programmatically-step-through-all-pictures-and-let-the-user-choose-c)

I am unable to adapt the macro from this post.

Plus I don't know the letters to set the "HD", "Print", or "Email" resolution in VBA. Is it ? :

```
SendKeys "%h", True
SendKeys "%p", True
SendKeys "%e", True
```

The code works when I manually run it inside PowerPoint.

When I launch as an automatic command-line from Python, sometimes it works, sometimes it runs the macro automatically but does not compress the pictures.
Plus, every time I run the macro it deactivates the "Num lock" pad button (maybe because of DoEvents ?).

```vb
Sub Compress_Picture_print_quality()
    Dim shp As Shape
    Dim sld As Slide
    Dim get_out As Boolean
    Dim ppt As Presentation
       
    get_out = False
    For Each sld In ActivePresentation.Slides
        sld.Select
        For Each shp In sld.Shapes
            If shp.Type = msoPicture Then
                shp.Select
                Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PicturesCompress"
                SendKeys "%(p)",True 'or i.g. w for web, or e for email compression
                SendKeys "%(a)",False
                SendKeys "(ENTER)",True
                DoEvents ' I think this desactivates the Num Lock pad button of my keyboard. I have no clue why so
                get_out = True
                Exit For
            End If
        Next shp
        If get_out Then
            Exit For
        End If
    Next sld

    'Now I want to save the presentation and close it without closing other open PowerPoint files

    With Application.ActivePresentation
        If Not .Saved And .Path <> "" Then .Save
    End With

    If PowerPoint.Application.Version >= 9 Then
        PowerPoint.Application.Visible = msoTrue
    End If
    PowerPoint.ActivePresentation.Window(1).Close
End Sub
```

Subprocess command to run VBA code.

```py
import os
import subprocess    
os.chdir(r"C:\my_dir")
path_to_ppt_exe = r"C:\POWERPNT.EXE"
command = path_to_ppt_exe + ' /M "presentation.ppt" Compress_Picture_print_quality'
subprocess.run(command)
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "free macro on demand" site. Try a search on _PowerPoint VBA batch compress pictures_ to find similar code that you can modify. We'll help you with debugging.

Comment: My apologies. I have a bit in a hurry. I have edited my post with what I have found and worked on. I explain more precisely some difficulties I am still encountering, especially when I run the VBA macro using a subprocess command-line

Comment: One very good answer would be to compress the pictures before you embed them.  Then, you have full control over what you're embedding.

Answer (score 1):

Each line contains a single letter with an underline, representing a keyboard shortcut with the Alt key. For example:

> Use default ... -- it means the shortcut is <Alt+u>

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I know already this box option in PowerPoint. I am actually trying to make this in VBA macro

Comment: The screenshop shows `letters` (shortcut) for different resolution.

Comment: I have edited my post in order to give more details of my issue